# ActionCable raising exception during rspec system spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, actioncable

I have a problem using ActionCable with system specs using Capybara. ActionCable is working perfectly on my development server, but when testing with system specs, it is unable to connect to Websockets.

The output from `/log/test.log` shows:

```ruby
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-15 18:17:04 +0900
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-15 18:17:04 +0900
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
WebSocket error occurred: undefined method `write_nonblock' for nil:NilClass
WebSocket error occurred: undefined method `write_nonblock' for nil:NilClass
WebSocket error occurred: undefined method `write_nonblock' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm using:

- ruby 2.4.1
- rails 5.1.4
- rspec 3.7.0
- capybara 2.13.0
- puma 3.10.0
- selenium-webdriver 3.6.0

I have tried:

```ruby
Capybara.server = :puma
```

This made no difference (probably since system specs are already using Puma).

**My attempt at debugging the issue:**

Looking closer at the error, the method `write_nonblock` is called on `nil`, which happens here on line 45:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/385825fb705446a1f11e82b65ca97a50d7e67898/actioncable/lib/action_cable/connection/stream.rb#L45

It seems like `@rack_hijack_io` gets set to `nil`, which likely happens in the `hijack_rack_socket` method here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/385825fb705446a1f11e82b65ca97a50d7e67898/actioncable/lib/action_cable/connection/stream.rb#L102

`@socket_object.env["rack.hijack_io"]` returns `nil`, so we don't have a `"rack.hijack_io"` key. So the error seems to be related to the Rack Hijacking API.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a bug in Puma and not in RSpec or your configuration.  You could verify this by swapping it temporarily for [thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin). Create a branch in git and comment out `gem 'puma'` and add `gem 'thin'` in the Gemfile.

Comment: https://github.com/puma/puma/commit/7cd363f7990f956334364ccdecf0b21f5fe65143

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @max. I tried switching to `thin`, and the error in `test.log` is gone. However, I now get `Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871074/rails-5-actioncable-is-not-returning-upgrade-headers-with-status-101-upgrade-res). I'll try to see if I can get some other server to work to isolate the problem to Puma.

Comment: Adding `config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock` to my `environments/test.rb` removes the error message from `test.log`. This is even working with `Puma`. I have no idea why though. However, the `connected`-callback in `window.App.cable.subscriptions.create` never gets called (https://gist.github.com/andreaslillebo/8ff8d7c022058f5ca21b2935f69a445f#file-mysubscription-js). This is working on `development`. When using selenium with chromium, opening the network-tab when the test is running, it seems to be connected though (https://gist.github.com/andreaslillebo/8ff8d7c022058f5ca21b2935f69a445f)

Comment: Rack::Lock prevents multiple simultaneous requests/connections.  Rails 5.1 shouldn't be including it at all unless you've opted out of concurrency by specifying `config.allow_concurrency = false` .  As for Puma, what output does it produce in your test run - Is it in "single mode" and does it state it's using multiple threads?

Comment: After removing `config.allow_concurrency = false` from `test.rb`, I no longer needed `config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock`. Puma didn't output anything during startup (probably since the default server in Rails 5.1 system tests has its output silenced). Registering a custom puma server results in this output (https://gist.github.com/andreaslillebo/70dcc1508c083f7acb8ea2943ea81477). It appears to be using 2 threads in cluster mode. The `connected`-callback still doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know details about your test but in my case, the issue was in `config.log_level = :debug` in `config/environments/[env]`.

Because ActionCable produces a lot of debugging information about broadcasting. For instance, if you have 100 connected clients your log file will be polluted with 100 messages for each broadcast.

PS: I caught this error on NGINX + Passenger(6.0.4) + GKE with Stackdriver logging.