# ActionCable in production repeated 101 responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm attempting to deploy a standalone ActionCable server for our rails app. The app is working locally in development mode fine but when deployed to production the client is unable to establish a connection. The problem manifests as the following:

[image]

These are repeated `101 Switching Protocol` requests with an upgrade response. The requests never go further than this and repeat at roughly six second intervals. On the server I'm running Puma and I can see the incoming requests:

[image]

I've ensured I'm sharing cookies between the main domain and the subdomain (and can see the cookies being passed) but I never see the connection get upgraded.

Some notes:

- The connection is not over SSL
- I've tested that our corporate firewall is not blocking WebSockets
- The cable server is being hosted on a GCP Cloud Compute instance
- Action cable is being run using Puma
- I can see some outgoing frames sent on the second WebSocket request but no incoming frames.

I'm out of ideas so would appreciate some thoughts on what I could try next to debug this!

Comment: what about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871074/rails-5-actioncable-is-not-returning-upgrade-headers-with-status-101-upgrade-res#37872152 and maybe there is some discussion about `http 101 actioncable`

Comment: I've been through almost everything on StackOverflow so far that could related to this! Unlike that post, I'm not using Thin but Puma as well.

Comment: did you read about the handshake in action cable http://blog.honeybadger.io/building-a-simple-websockets-server-from-scratch-in-ruby/ will you include any settings about your server in this post? also this post has some interesting info but you should translate it to english http://www.jianshu.com/p/f08393da80b5

Answer (score 2):

So I eventually got to the bottom of this. For those following in my footsteps it was an issue around cookie name-spacing. Essentially the cookies were not being set the domain level so therefore were not being shared with the cable server (which was on a subdomain).

If you're suffering a similar issue try running the cable server in development mode while the app runs in production - the additional log output should make it easier to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue when the connection to Redis was failing on the server. I had an invalid URL associated with Redis, fixing that fixed the issue for me.